# ARIMA Python - predict function does not take date as input

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, time-series, arima

I have a time series input data where the time is irregular as below: data_series_final is the data series

```
Price      Date
9654    28.04.2013
10040   01.01.2014
10381   01.01.2017
10040   04.07.2016
11011   02.04.2018
10381   05.01.2018
10849   05.02.2018
11011   05.03.2018
11602   07.05.2018
```

Case 1: I did not regularize the intervals and went on to stationarize the data using log and difference method

```
ds_log = np.log(data_series_final)
data_diff_log = ds_log.diff(periods=1)
data_diff_log =  data_diff_log.dropna()

data_diff_log_train = data_diff_log[0:5]
data_diff_log_test = data_diff_log[5:]
```

The data was pretty stationary and the training model followed the ARIMA fitted model. But when I ran the predict function on ARIMA, and passed in the dates as input parameter, I got the following error:

```
model_arima = ARIMA(data_diff_log_train, order=(0,0,2))
model_arima_fit = model_arima.fit()
predict_arima=[]
predict_arima = model_arima_fit.forecast(steps=2)[0]

predictions = model_arima_fit.predict(start='2020-01-01', end='2021-01-01')
```

KeyError: '2020-01-01'
  TypeError: an integer is required

KeyError: 'The `start` argument could not be matched to a location related   to   the index of the data.'

Case 2: I tried to regularize the time interval by padding the data,

```
#
#Upsampling and Interpolating data 

data_upsampled = data_series_final.resample('D', convention='start').asfreq()
data_upsampled = upsampled.interpolate(method='linear')
#data_upsampled = data_series_final.resample('D', fill_method = 'ffill')
```

But i could not stationarize the data as there were peaks in values. Also i got the same error as mentioned above and was not able to send in datetime as parameter.

Can someone please help?